# Debugger not attaching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-debug

Ever since upgrading my Android Studio / Android versions, everything's just hopelessly broken for no good reason.

I can't even attach the debugger anymore and things are throwing errors in the weirdest ways. I'd like to just get the darn debugger working. It just hangs on "Waiting for Debugger" and nothing is happening.

Is this a common problem with the new Android Studio version? I am trying to debug on an Android 8.1 (API 27) emulated device.

In Logcat it shows "No Debuggable Devices" in the dropdown. The debugger seems to work when I use an older device, e.g. API 25.

Comment: Yeah. I faced this issue a lot of times. I couldn't find any solution yet. I just detach the USB cable or restart Android Studio works fine for me.